# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_descendants'

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am using django mptt

Here is my view:

```
    def category(request, path, instance, extra):
        if instance:
            instance.save()

        queryset = Product.objects.filter(category__in=instance.get_descendants(include_self=True))

        color = request.GET.get('q')

        if color:
            queryset = Product.objects.filter(optiongroup__option = color )

        return render(
            request,
            'products/prodgrid.html',
            {
                'instance': instance,
                'children': instance.get_children() if instance else Category.objects.root_nodes(),
                'queryset': queryset,
            }
        )
```

Here is the traceback

```
Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\plump\Plumpin\src\mptt_urls\__init__.py" in __call__
  35.         return self.view(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\plump\Plumpin\src\products\views.py" in category
  35.     queryset = Product.objects.filter(category__in=instance.get_descendants(include_self=True))

Exception Type: AttributeError at /category/women/women-clothing/dresses/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_descendants'
```

Here is template

```
{% for color in instance.get_colors %}
                        <li><label for="{{color.value}}"><input type="checkbox" id="{{color.value}}" group = "color"  value="{{ color.value }}"/><a href="{{ instance.get_absolute_url }}/?color={{ color.value }}">{{ color.value }}</a></label></li>
                        {% endfor %}
```

Where am I going wrong with this?

How can I improve the code?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing on this line:

```
queryset = Product.objects.filter(category__in=instance.get_descendants(include_self=True))
```

because instance is `None`. You need to figure out why the `category` method has been called with `instance=None`. Where do you expect the instance to be set?

Comment: the above queryset gives me all the products within a particular category instance...i am trying to further filter the queryset based on color...

Comment: You've misunderstood my answer. The problem is not that queryset, it is that you are trying to run it when `instance=None`. What is instance meant to be? How do you expect it to be set?

Comment: i get u...when i click on the color checkbox ,,,the instance becomes none....thats why it is popping that error ...why it is happening that way ?

Comment: It looks like you are using [django-mptt-urls](https://github.com/c0ntribut0r/django-mptt-urls). My guess it that either you have misconfigured it, or you have hit a bug in it. I'm not familiar with the package so I don't know why it's not working. Hope you figure it out.

Comment: yeah i was trying to generate urls using that package...but customizing is a bit trouble

Comment: i was wondering what is the best way to create these product filters?

Comment: Sorry, that's a pretty broad question, I can't answer it.